# Magento rewrite 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option' not working?

Tags: overrides

below is my config.xml files code with path.

> app/code/local/Eventprice/Meta/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eventprice_Meta>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Eventprice_Meta>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <eventprice_meta>
                <class>Eventprice_Meta_Model</class>
            </eventprice_meta>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <eventprice_sql>
                <setup>
                    <module>Eventprice_Meta</module>
                </setup>
            </eventprice_sql>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <settings>
                <class>Eventprice_Meta_Block</class>
            </settings>
            <adminhtml> 
                <rewrite>
                     <catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
                        Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option
                    </catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Below is my Option.php file code with path.

> code/local/Eventprice/Meta/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php

```
<?php
class Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option 
extends 
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('sphere/catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml');
        $this->setCanReadPrice(true);
        $this->setCanEditPrice(true);
    }

}
```

and below is the path of my template file.

> /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sphere/catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml

i didn't change anything in code.

but the rewrite is not working my template file is not called. please correct me where i create a mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are main issue in space in `config.xml.`

```
<catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option</catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
```

from

```
<catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
                        Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option
                    </catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
```

Comment: good catch @amit +1 from me